# How to append div element after image tag using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have used jquery to append span element after image tag. But the span element showing inside the image tage. I am moving the caption from one place to another so if i use insertafter it gets dulicated on another place. Please check with the following code  and guide me to solve this

```
$(".wf_captionfirst").appendTo($("#articlespace img"));
```

Output shows

```
<img src="" ><span class="wf_captionfirst">adsfasdff</span></img>
```

Comment: Just use `$("<span class='wf_captionfirst'>adsfasdff</span>").insertAfter("img");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `.insertAfter()`. This will insert the selected element after each `img`.

```
$(".wf_captionfirst").insertAfter($("#articlespace img"));
```

---

If you want to insert at one img then you could use pseudo selectors;

```
$(".wf_captionfirst").insertAfter($("#articlespace img:first-of-type"));
```

or specify by ID or Class;

```
$(".wf_captionfirst").insertAfter($("#articlespace .imageContainer"));
$(".wf_captionfirst").insertAfter($("#articlespace #imageContainer"));
```

---

insertAfter doesn't duplicate the element IF there is only 1 target. Demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".move").click(function() {
    $(".moveMe").insertAfter(".A");
  });
});
```

```css
.A {
  padding: 40px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.B {
  padding: 40px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.moveMe {
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="move">Move</button>

<div class="moveMe">
  Test
</div>

<div class="A">

</div>

<div class="B">

</div>
```

Comment: I am moving the caption from one place to another so if i use insertafter it gets dulicated on another place

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by duplicate. I updated the answer with a demo, it doesn't duplicate it.

Comment: ACtually i m using insertafter but the element remain on that place and insert after works also. Both are showing

Comment: @jack Include your full HTML. We don't know where `.wf_captionfirst` is located.

Comment: <div id="articlespace">
<img src="img/testw.jpg"></div>
<p><span class="wf_caption" style="margin-left: 9px; float: right; margin-bottom: 9px; max-width: 400px; display: inherit;"><img src="/images/asdfasdf-asdfasdf.jpg">asdfasdfasfdasdf</span></p>

Comment: @jack please edit the question and include the full html. We need to see where `wf_captionfirst` is.